# Fixing encoding issue in Excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel file and It has weird characters in it like stated below:

[image]

For instance: 4. row should be "Soirée Filles" instead of "SoirГ©e Filles" I think there is an encoding issue. I tried to save as in "CSV" format by changing "Web Options" like below but it did not work. How can I fix that issue?

[image]

Comment: The "save as type" dropdown should have another option that says `CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited) (*.csv)`

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 There is no like that option, I have only CSV (Comma Delimited), CSV (MS-DOS), CSV (Machintosh) and as I said I have already tried to change web options settings

Comment: I'm not quite sure that would have solved the problem anyways. What version of excel are you using and what through what method does this data get added to excel?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 The file was sent from somewhere, I do not know how they added. My office version is Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016.

Comment: Maybe you can open the CSV file with notepad and then save it as UTF-8.